# ms access search for record with multiple combobox

Tags: database, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2013

I have form with several comboboxes set to filter my database by record. For example I have: product, type and size columns and according to this i have dynamically changing comboboxes. So what I want is to find a record that matches all choices from combobox. Like this. [image]

but there is one "but".

[image]

If i choose type 6s and then I choose 64gb it returns to value 5s and 64gb. I mean It searches the first record in size column according to combobos so I want somehow to find the first record that matches all three comboboxes.

Comment: It looks like there's a problem with your query. Could you post the SQL code of the query giving you poor results? Or is this a bound form?

Comment: it's a bound form. on combobox i have SearchForResult function and in one of the "where condition" it has:   ="[size] = " & "'" &[Forms]![Table1]![sizes]& "'"

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this with a bound form. Is your form name really "Table1"? (`[Forms]![Table1]` looks odd)? Someone else may need to chime in, I'm lost.

Comment: Sorry about that I said it was bound form, but I really don't know what it is. I just knew it's not SQL code. And yeah it's name is Table1 beacuse it's like a test form to understand how the real form should work. And if it helps you I made a querry with SQL code and it works implacably it's: "SELECT table.ID, table.product, table.type, table.size, table.maker
FROM product
WHERE product = "Iphone" And type = "5s" And size = "64gb";
" I want my form to work the same way this SQL code works

Comment: show us this `SearchForResult` function. Do you call it each time a value change in any combobox?

Comment: Yes. And I want value to change after last combobox updates, but I cant write where condition for last combobox so it will apply search according on multiple comboboxes. It's  like: ="[size] = " & "'" & [Forms]![Table1]![sizes] & "'"  sizes- is my combobox name. I thought it would be like: ="[size] = " & "'" & [Forms]![Table1]![sizes] & "'" And "[type] = " & "'" & [Forms]![Table1]![types] & "'" But it won't work.